# How to tell Electron packager to use my custom electron config file?

Tags: angularjs, electron, electron-packager

I successfully run my Angular 2 app via electron from app root folder. I build the app into `dist` folder by running:

```
ng build --env=prod
```

and then I just run:

```
electron electron.conf.js
```

Where in `electron.conf.js` I run local webserver to serve files from `dist`

```
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/dist')).listen(8997, function(){
    console.log('Webserver for electron is running on port 8997...');
});
mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8997');
```

I need this approach because I use gapi.js which will not initialize from `file:///` protocol and needs `http(s)`.

This works well, but I struggle to successfully launch the electron app when I package it as Windows .exe file. When I make the exe package as following (from app root dir):

```
electron-packager . MyAppName --platform=win32 --arch=x64
```

and then launch the MyApp.exe, it fails with:

```
Cannot find module MyApp/resources/app/index.js
```

It seems like electron running via electron-packager is trying serve the app via default `file://` protocol (while all the files are actually in `MyApp/resources/app/dist/index.js` and should be served via http).

How can I tell electron-packager to use my `electron.conf.js` which will launch my local webserver?

Answer (score 0):

so, the whole trick is to add `index.js` file to the root project directory and the `index.js` is meant to inlude the electron app conf, e.g.:

```
const electron = require('electron')
var app = electron.app;
app.on('ready', function () {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1200, height: 900 });
    mainWindow.loadURL('my-url-here');
})
```

after bunding the app with electron-packager, this `index.js` is copied to `resources/app/index.js` and used as electron load config when the .exe is launched.